# Spinner is not displaying UTF-8 characters

Tags: android, utf-8, spinner

I need help with my spinners.

The Spinner is configured with the following code...

```
    List<String> lCountries = (Arrays.asList(Countries().split(";")));
  CharSequence[] csCountries = lCountries.toArray(new CharSequence[lCountries.size()]);

  final Spinner sCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country);
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aCountry = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, csCountries);
  aCountry.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  sCountry.setAdapter(aCountry);
```

The List calls the class [`Countries()`] and this is the code....

```
   URL requestURL = new URL("http://www.merso.eu/phone/xml/Country.php");
   URLConnection connection = requestURL.openConnection();

   InputStream isCountry = connection.getInputStream();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isCountry, "UTF-8"));

   StringBuilder sbCountry = new StringBuilder();
   String line;

   sbCountry.append("Select a Country;");

   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     sbCountry.append(line);
   }
   Countries = sbCountry.toString();
```

I have changed the UTF8 to all possible alterations utf-8, utf8, UTF-8, UTF8 and nothing at all.

I knwow the list from the server is OK, as it can be run on any browser and it returns the list with UTF-8 characters.

What am I missing? Do I have to type UTF-8 somewhere else?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks;
Ramón

Answer (score 1):

Your url declares a content-type :

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

so your reader should be

```
new InputStreamReader(isCountry, "ISO-8859-1")
```

Better even, by using HttpClient instead of URLConnection, you can get the content type : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContentType%28%29